# Selenium Webdriver: Unable to click elements in IE 11/Windows 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, ui-automation

I am unable to click elements with script in IE11. Though the same code is working fine for Chrome. 
Have tried with Webdriver click, Actions class, as well as JavascriptExecuter.

Details: Windows 10, IE 11, IEDriver 3.4.0

The browser opens normally, navigates to the url, but the click never happens and the test case also passes.

Attaching code snippets

pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

JavascriptExecuter Code

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
```

Actions Class

```
Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
    ob.moveToElement(we);
    ob.click(we);
    Action action  = ob.build();
    action.perform();
```

Driver Code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver" , "IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get(url);
```

Comment: I'll point out that you asked the driver to introduce flakiness into your code by explicitly setting a capability to do so. If you're using that capability to avoid an exception, then that means either you haven't configured the browser's Protected Mode settings properly. Not doing so can lead to wildly unpredictable results, including elements not being clicked.

Comment: @JimEvans: Not working even after removing that capability. Also, the protected mode settings are also turned off for all zones.

Comment: It won't work with windows 10 and I.E 11 so work with chrome or Firefox. No use of troubleshooting . I did alot but in vain .

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar: got it working with JavascriptExecuter. Was doing a very silly mistake while testing, with the class and method name. But still I wonder why Webdriver and Action not working

Comment: Great @iamvroon .!! I will try it too